# How to modify URL Structure as per our requirement

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting, directory-structure, urlslug

As per the SEO standards, I want to modify my URL Structure.

For example :

I have a domain name

```
domain.com/blog/
```

on which I have installed WordPress.

Now while posting any blog I am getting my URL as

```
domain.com/blog/category-name/post-name
```

Now, I need to have my post URL as

```
domain.com/category-name/post-name
```

Similarly, for each category and its related post, I need to modify the URL structure as mentioned above.

Keeping in mind that my domain.com is developed on any other platform, and we have to modify WordPress installed directory/URL domain.com/blog as per our requirement.

Subfolder name coming in between domain name and category name while editing it with WordPress admin dashboard custom permalink.

[image: Custom Permalink Image]

Not having any idea about this URL structure modification.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

With ,htaccess

This should change domain.com/blog/ to domain.com/

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Install Wordpress directly to domain.com, instead of sub folder 'blog'. Then URL will work as expected.

Otherwise can simply use this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/

The plugin works with all custom post types and taxonomies, as well as many popular third-party plugins.

Comment: I tried this plugin but it's not solving the problem I am looking for. I need to hide the /blog from the URL mentioned in the image before each category. And I don't find it to be solved with the Permalink settings. 

Thank You for your reply :)

Comment: Install wordpress directly to domain.com, instead of sub folder 'blog'. Then URL will work as expected

Comment: Yes, that's one of the solutions but the issue is that domain.com is running on any other platform and has given me WordPress installed on domain.com/blog/ & now asking me to have the URL structure as domain.com/categories-name/post-name with the same WordPress installed directory.

Comment: One solution I am getting is that for each category I should install WordPress separately. But it'll increase the workload, that's why the above-given solution by me was also rejected. And I am stuck.